# Is groovy programming language Synchronous or Asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, groovy, synchronous

Can anybody tell? Is groovy a Synchronous or Asynchronous programming language.

It seems, It is Asynchronous but for confirmation  i am asking it. I did not get any solution whether is it Synchronous or Asynchronous language on google.

Please tell me how to use groovy as synchronous in script I have below code which doesn't completes it execution and groovy executes next line of code.

```
def expCmp="expdp HR/HR@"+srcOrclName+" directory=Export DUMPFILE="+schema+".dmp LOGFILE="+schema+".log SCHEMAS="+schema+""
proc = expCmp.execute()

println("Data export started.")
```

The execution of below line doesn't completes and groovy executes next line which is println("Data export started.").

```
proc = expCmp.execute()
```

So How can I stop groovy until above command completes it should not execute next line of code.

If we can run groovy script as synchronous, please tell let me know and give one example which synchronous call of groovy script.
Note: Please don't write code using class. make sure it is groovy script only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Groovy can be used in both a synchronous and asynchronous way, depending on how you use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when you run (cleaned up a bit to make it more *Groovy*)

```
def expCmp="expdp HR/HR@${srcOrclName} directory=Export DUMPFILE=${schema}.dmp LOGFILE=${schema}.log SCHEMAS=${schema}"
def proc = expCmp.execute()
```

That creates a new shell process and runs it asynchronously.

To wait for it to finish, simply put:

```
proc.waitForProcessOutput()
```

before your line:

```
println "Data export finished."
```